# If $\mu$ is a measure on $X$ and, for each $x$, $\nu_x$ is a measure on $Y$, what is the measure $\int \nu_x d\mu(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> If $\mu$ is a measure on $X$ and, for each $x$, $\nu_x$ is a measure on $Y$, what is the measure $\int \nu_x d\mu(x)$?

We have two measure spaces $X$ and $Y$, and we consider their product $Z = X \times Y$. The space $X$ comes with a measure $\mu$, and $Y$ comes with a collection of measures $\nu_x$ for each $x \in X$. Given any measurable $f : X \times Y \to \mathbb{R}$, we consider the natural integral $$\int_X \int_Y f(x, y) d\nu_x(y) d\mu(x).$$ If everything is nice, we should get a measure on $Z$.

I have two questions:

1. What is this measure called?
2. Is there a reverse process where we start with measures on $Z$ and $X$ and factor the $Z$-measure over the $X$-measure and get a measure on each fibre $\{x\} \times Y$?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for: Naïvely this looks like conditioning (think of $\nu_x$ as the "conditional distribution" of $y$ given $X=x$). Then the measure that you've written is the "joint distribution" of $(X,Y)$. For your second question, that is the "conditional distribution" of $Y$ given $X=x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2. The answer is "Yes, under suitable conditions". This reverse process is called the disintegration of the measure on $Z$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disintegration_theorem for example. The notion is very closely related to conditional distributions. For more on this see the article of Chang and Pollard "Conditioning as Disintegration" [*Statist. Neerlandica*, vol. 51 (1997) pp. 287–317] http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1467-9574.00056/abstract;jsessionid=8B62D4B3E9376B1F913E8A70F4A0E1E4.f04t04 .